# ember.js - update form in modal and on its own route?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Within a 3.x Ember.js app I want to show the user an update form overload over the existing screen.

The existing screen would be on a route '\vegetables' and the update form would be on '\vegetables\update\carrots'. If the update was a conventional form there wouldn't be a problem but how do I go about displaying a form overlaid on the existing form ? Is there an add-on for this ?

I'm using bootstrap to style the ui and so bootstrap modals are available but I'm not sure how that would fit into a template ?

I have seen a number of addons but they all seem to be aimed at a modal appearing within the current route and for reasons of authentication/authorization I want a seperate route for this update operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice addon for this called [ember-routable-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-routable-modal)

In your route, you extend their mixin:

```
// app/routes/example.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ModalRouteMixin from 'ember-routable-modal/mixins/route';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ModalRouteMixin, {
});
```

And then use some special markup:

```
// app/templates/example.hbs
<div class="routable-modal--dialog">
    <div class="routable-modal--content">
        <div class="routable-modal--header">
            {{routable-modal-close-button class="routable-modal--close"}}
            <h4 class="routable-modal--title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="routable-modal--body">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Now whenever you navigate to /example, through the usual {{link-to}}
>   helper or by calling this.transitionTo() within a route, the example
>   modal will render on top of your currently active route. If you load
>   the page from the /example URL directly, the closest parent route will
>   be rendered underneath the modal.
>
> You are free to delete the provided template and build your own dialog
>   component if you wish, the addon is flexible.

If you feel like rolling your own, use that addon as inspiration. The main idea here is that to leverage the [renderTemplate](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/Route/methods/renderTemplate?anchor=renderTemplate) route hook to render elsewhere

```
renderTemplate() {
    this.render({
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'routable-modal-outlet'
    });
}
```

Comment: That's excellent thanks. I've tried it out and it's working nicely.